# Creating a child process in Erlang correctly

Tags: sockets, erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to create a child process for each connection and the problem is, it won't return until the the child process exited.

```
-module(nodesupervisor).

-export([start_link/0, init/1, start_child/2]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 5, 10},[]}}.

start_child(_sup, Socket) -> % pass the returned value of start_link and user's socket
    ChildSpec = {nodemod, {nodemod, start_link_node, [Socket]},
                 permanent, 5000, worker, [nodemod]},
    io:fwrite("supervisor : ~p~n", [supervisor:start_child(_sup, ChildSpec)]). % this wont return until the process finished or failed.
```

The function `start_child` as far as I know should return immediately but it only return if the new child exited.

How do I fix it?

I have tried different implementations and all of them returned only when child process exited.

Comment: Could you show the code for the `nodemod:start_link_node/1` function? I suspect that's where the problem lies - it should start the process and return immediately, but maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your supervisor does not have this line:

```
-behavior(supervisor).
```

...which is required.

> the function start_child as far as i know should return immediately
> but it only return if the new child exited.

If your child is a `gen_server`, the gen_server docs say:

> The gen_server process calls Module:init/1 to initialize. To ensure a
> synchronized startup procedure, start_link/3,4 does not return until
> Module:init/1 has returned.
>
> https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-3

`genserver:start_link()` returns the pid of the gen_server:

```
{ok, Pid :: pid()} | 
ignore | 
{error, Reason :: term()}
```

and `supervisor:start_child()` returns

```
{ok, Child :: child()}
```

where `child()` is the pid of the gen_server.  So it seems logical that `supervisor:start_child()` cannot return until `gen_server:start_link()` returns, and `gen_server:start_link()` can't return until `nodemod:init()` returns.  I put a `timer:sleep(10000)` in my child's `init()` function, and `supervisor:start_child()` hung for 10 seconds.  Is your nodemod a gen_server? Are you doing something in `nodemod:init()` that hangs?

Here are some other relevant passages from the docs describing dynamic supervisors:

> A supervisor can have one of the following restart strategies...:
>
> ...
>
> simple_one_for_one - A simplified one_for_one supervisor, where all
> child processes are dynamically added instances of the same process
> type, that is, running the same code.
>
> https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#supervision-principles

...

> Notice that when the restart strategy is simple_one_for_one, the list
> of child specifications must be a list with one child specification
> only. (The child specification identifier is ignored.) No child
> process is then started during the initialization phase, but all
> children are assumed to be started dynamically using start_child/2.
>
> https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#Module:init-1

...

> When started, the supervisor does not start any child processes.
> Instead, all child processes are added dynamically by calling:
>
> **supervisor:start_child(Sup, List)**
> Sup is the pid, or name, of the supervisor.
> List is an arbitrary list of terms, which are added to the
> list of arguments specified in the child specification.
> If the start function is specified as {M, F, A}, the child process is started by
> calling apply(M, F, A++List).
>
> https://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#simplified-one_for_one-supervisors

Here's an example of a `simple_one_for_one` dynamic supervisor:

**nodes_supervisor.erl**:

```
-module(nodes_supervisor).

-behavior(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).


start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link(
      {local, ?MODULE},  % Name to register for this process.
      ?MODULE,           % Module containing callback function init().
      []                 % Args for init().
     ).

init([]) ->
    SupFlags = #{strategy => simple_one_for_one, intensity => 5, period => 10},
    ChildSpecs = [#{id => node,
                    start => {node, start_link_node, [5]},
                    % The line above says that start_link_node() will have arity 1 
                    % (one element in the list of args), but supervisor:start_child()
                    % will add args to [5], using [5] ++ list2, where list2 comes
                    % from the second arg to supervisor:start_child(). 
                    % So the arity of start_link_node() needs to match the number of 
                    % args in [5] ++ list2.
                               
                    restart => permanent,
                    shutdown => 5000,
                    type => worker,
                    modules => [node]}],
    {ok, {SupFlags, ChildSpecs}}.
```

**node.erl**:

```
-module(node).

-behavior(gen_server).

-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_call/3]).
-export([start_link_node/3]).

start_link_node(Arg1, Socket, Arg3) ->  % The arity has to match the number of args 
                                        % specified in the child_spec list plus the number 
                                        % of args supplied in the list which is the second
                                        % argument in the call to supervisor:start_child() 
    gen_server:start_link(
      ?MODULE,   % Module containing the callback functions: init(), handle_cast(), etc.
      [Socket, Arg1, Arg3],   % Args sent to init().
      []         % Options for starting gen_server.
    ).

init([Socket|_Rest]) ->
    % Or, create the socket here.
    io:format("Starting node child process: ~w~n", [self()]),
    NumberOfTimesDoSomethingWasCalled = 0,
    {ok, {Socket, NumberOfTimesDoSomethingWasCalled}}. % 2nd element of outer tuple will be  
                                                       % the initial state of the gen_server.

handle_cast(do_something, State) ->
    {Socket, CallCount} = State,
    io:format("do_something with Socket: ~w~n", [Socket]),

    NewCallCount = CallCount+1,
    io:format("CallCount is: ~w~n", [NewCallCount]),

    NewState = {Socket, NewCallCount},
    {noreply, NewState};
handle_cast(something_else, State) ->
    io:format("Doing something else."),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_call(task1, _From, State) ->
    Msg = {hello, 10},
    {reply, Msg, State}.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/supervisor_my% erl
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.3.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V12.3.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(node).                                  
{ok,node}

2> c(node_supervisor).                       
{ok,node_supervisor}

3> {ok, Sup} = node_supervisor:start_link(). 
{ok,<0.95.0>}

4> Socket = a_socket.                                       
a_socket

5> {ok, Node1} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, [Socket, 10]). 
Starting node child process: <0.98.0>
{ok,<0.98.0>}

6> gen_server:cast(Node1, do_something).                    
do_something with Socket: a_socket
ok
CallCount is: 1

7> gen_server:cast(Node1, do_something).                   
do_something with Socket: a_socket
ok
CallCount is: 2

8> Socket2 = b_socket.                                      
b_socket

9> {ok, Node2} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, [Socket2, 30]).
Starting node child process: <0.103.0>
{ok,<0.103.0>}

10> gen_server:cast(Node2, do_something).                    
do_something with Socket: b_socket
ok
CallCount is: 1
```